# Error:Unable to resolve dependency...Could not resolve project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have problem with Gradle building for Android. I tried a lot of methods for resolve this problem but nothing is not working. I need help.

Gradle version: 4.4
Gradle plugin: 3.0.1

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        flavorDimensions "group1"
        productFlavors {
            server {
                versionName '0.1'
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 26
                testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
                versionCode 1
                dimension "group1"
            }
            mock {
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 26
                testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
                versionCode 1
                versionName '0.1'
                dimension "group1"
            }
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.3'
        annotationProcessor 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.5.3'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
        annotationProcessor  'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
        implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.5-android'
        implementation 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.9'
        implementation project(':vksdk_library')
    }
```

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@serverDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :vksdk_library.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@mockDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :vksdk_library.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@mockDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :vksdk_library.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@serverRelease/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :vksdk_library.

Comment: Do you have a module named `vksdk_library` within your open project?

Comment: Yes, I have this module

Comment: could you post the app level build gradle?

Answer (score 1):

[As from docs, gradle dependency section](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk) You can use

```
implementation 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.9'
```

instead of adding the whole project yourself

**Note:** you also must have maven support added in your project

[**As mentioned here in docs**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html) rest leave it gradle to download and link library